# How do I pass in an updated value into a new separate component?

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, components, undefined

I want the updated value to pass into a new components "ExpandDevelopment" after making a selection "Development" in the Department selection field.

This is a list that populates the Department Field

```
export const getDepartmentCollection = ()=>([
    { id: '1', title: 'Development' },
    { id: '2', title: 'Marketing' },
    { id: '3', title: 'Accounting' },
    { id: '4', title: 'HR' },
])
```

This is where the user can select from the Department dropdown menu.

```
<Controls.Select
    name="departmentId"
    label="Department"
    value={values.departmentId}
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    options={employeeService.getDepartmentCollection()}
    error={errors.departmentId}
/>
```

Once the user makes a selection, I want to pass the new value into this new component here.

```
  const ExpandDevelopment = (fieldValue = values) => {
    if (fieldValue.departmentId === "Development") {
        return (
          <Controls.Input
            label="Developer Position"
            name="developerPosition"
            value={values.developerPosition}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
    }
  };
```

However, the `fieldValue.departmentID` is rendering as undefined.

If you want to have a deeper dive into how this code works (/page/Employees/EmployeeForm) - CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-river-9diyw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into your code and made some changes. you might want to tweak a little bit on the validate code .

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-fast-7rdzc?file=/src/pages/Employees/EmployeeForm.js)

Comment: can you accept and upvote the answer if it works :-)

Comment: Just did. I cannot upvote yet since I am new.